# How to enable gpu in tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

From my searching result, seems tensorflow 2 automatically will use available gpu. I have a rtx 2080, but when i run the code  `print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))` it gives `Num GPUs Available:  0`. My tensorflow version is 2.4.x. And I am using jupyter notebook.
What should I do to enable the gpu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please install TensorFlow using the command `pip install tf-nightly-gpu` and let us know if it works as it worked for me.

try below code snippet, it will return the flag True, if there are available GPUs

`tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)`

#### Update

`pip install tf-nightly`
insides of
`pip install tf-nightly-gpu`

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Tensorflow-GPU in Windows

1. Download and install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 with update 3

"Search on Google using the same name and download the ISO image file and mount it. Install MSVS with visualc++ and python under programming language section. Rest is default.

2. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from nvidia site.
3. Download CuDNN by making free account. CUDNN 7.5.1 is compatible with CUDA 10.0
4. Extract the files and paste the files from folders in CUDNN to CUDA in the same folder.
5. set path of "bin" and "libnvvp" under system variable from CUDA folder in NVIDIA in program files in C.
6. using pip in cmd download tensorflow-gpu version 1.15.0

   pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
7. Install all the other dependencies.
   numpy
   sklearn
   scipy
   pandas
   imutils
   matplotlib etc.
8. Download Keras using same command.

Test tensorflow installation using following code:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

import tensorflow as tf

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

Note:- Version Compatibility may be arises but not sure.

Comment: It's sufficient to install MS VC++ Redistributable rather than the full-blown VS.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the right version `cuda` and `cudnn` . Read https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu and https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source